# Negating the Unique Existential quantification, or Uniqueness quantification

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Ok, I am attempting to negate the following

∃!x∈U, P(x)

I understand this to mean "There exists only one (unique) x which is inside of the domain U such that P(x)"

so ¬(∃!x∈U, P(x))

I understand this to mean: "There does not exist only one x which is a proper subset of U such that not P(x)"

Now to carry out the negation I Understand I can break down
∃!xP(x) to be

∃x(P(x)∧∀y(P(y)→y=x))

The Negation of this is going to be

∀x(¬P(x)∨∃y(P(y)∧y≠x))

So then the whole negation should be

∀x⊂U(¬P(x)∨∃y(P(y)∧y≠x))

Is this correct?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your MSE posts. As for the maths, your reasoning looks OK apart from $\subset$ where you mean $\in$..  The last formula might be clearer if you wrote it using an implication: $\forall x \in U(P(x) \Rightarrow (\exists y (P(y) \land x \neq y)))$. Or equivalently $(\forall x \in U(\lnot P(x)) \lor(\exists x, y \in U(P(x) \land P(y) \land x \neq y))$.

Comment: Personally, (expressing the idea in English), I would negate a statement like "There exists a unique $x$ such that $P(x)$" as follows:  [It is not the case that there exists an $x$ such that $P(x)$] **or** [There exists $x,y$ such that $P(x)$ and $P(y)$ and $x \neq y$].